# Add a slidedown effect to bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to add a slidedown effect on Bootstrap fixed to top navbar. The fixed navbar appears when the user scrolls down to the height of the normal navbar. I am doing this by adding and removing the `navbar-fixed-top` class to the navbar. Here are the final non-working code I have, which toggles the display of the navbar instead of sliding it down. Please help..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $navheight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= $navheight) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top sticky-nav').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top sticky-nav');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sticky-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-body">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So there is some strangeness with the sticky placement and the sliding.  I believe I was able to come close to what you desired with some trikery with margins and animate.  See what you think.

If your wondering why I'm using 'one' all over the place.  'one' only executes the handler once.  I'm attempting to use it to reduce the number of times the handler is invoked while it is operating.  Scroll fires -a lot-.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $navbar = $('.navbar'),
      navheight = $navbar.outerHeight(),
      $window = $(window);
  
  function toggleNavBar() {
    var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
    
    if (scroll >= navheight) {
      if (!$navbar.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')) {
        $navbar.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        $navbar.css('margin-top', -navheight);
        $navbar.animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 500, function() {
          $window.one('scroll', toggleNavBar);
        });
      } else {
        $window.one('scroll', toggleNavBar);
      }
    } else {
      if ($navbar.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top')) {
        $navbar.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      }
      
      $window.one('scroll', toggleNavBar);
    }
  }
  
  $window.one('scroll', toggleNavBar);
});
```

```css
.content{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-body">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="content">

</div>
</div>
```